# Writing path for sftp server python

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I am using `pysftp` on `Python` and am trying to run a loop for a certain directory in the sftp server.

I don't know how to write the directory paths on sftp servers. I thought that connecting to the server and just writing the directory as below would work, but it doesn't. Please let me know how to write sftp paths so that python can read them.

```
sftp =  pysftp.Connection('128.59.164.112', username = '', password = '');
source = sftp.u\'weatherForecast\'/dataRAW/2004/grib/tmax/
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: I got a syntax errors before, but now I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough trial and error I figured it out.

```
source = 'weatherForecast/dataRAW/2004/grib/tmax/'
destination= 'sftp.u\'weatherForecast\'/csv/2004/tmax'
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pysftp

sftp = pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret')
sftp.chdir('/home/user/development/stackoverflow')
ls = sftp.listdir()
for filename in ls:
    print filename
```

You should read this: http://pysftp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

PS1: ; is optional in Python, but not Pythonic.